# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read' raises while using AudioSegment get_file() command

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am currently working on a speech to text project. I tried the code in the following video
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B5A1bMi4dJI", and received :

```
 Line 29, in <module>
    clip = AudioSegment().from_file(data)

  File "C:\Users\efeba\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 213, in __init__
    data = data if isinstance(data, (basestring, bytes)) else data.read()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Here is my whole code :

```
import torch
from transformers import Wav2Vec2ForCTC, Wav2Vec2Processor
import speech_recognition as sr
from pydub import AudioSegment
import io

r = sr.Recognizer()


tokenizer = Wav2Vec2Processor.from_pretrained("cahya/wav2vec2-base-turkish")
model = Wav2Vec2ForCTC.from_pretrained("cahya/wav2vec2-base-turkish")


with sr.Microphone(sample_rate=16000) as source: 
    print("You can start speaking now") 
    while True: 
        audio = r.listen(source) 
        data = io.BytesIO(audio.get_wav_data())
        
        clip = AudioSegment().from_file(data)
        x    = torch.FloatTensor(clip.get_array_of_samples())
        
        
        inputs = tokenizer(x, sampling_rate = 16000, return_tensors = 'pt', padding = 'longest' ).input_values
        logits = model(inputs).logits
        tokens = torch.argmax(logits, dim = -1)
        text   = tokenizer.batch_decode(tokens)
        
        print(str(text).lower())
```

Error occurs right after I start to talk. I could not understand what causes this error, so i couldn't solve.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: `io.BytesIO(audio.get_wav_data())` is returning `None`.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the parentheses on the following line:

```
AudioSegment().from_file(data)
Rather, use
AudioSegment.from_file(data)
```

`AudioSegment` is a method, not a function.